# How to do arithmetic on registered variables in ansible?

Tags: math, ansible

I'm writing a health-check playbook, and when a host is clustered (VCS), I want to make sure all cluster Service Groups are running.
The output of hastatus looks like this:

```
[root@node1 ~]# hastatus -sum

-- SYSTEM STATE
-- System               State                Frozen

A  node1                RUNNING              0
A  node2                RUNNING              0

-- GROUP STATE
-- Group           System               Probed     AutoDisabled    State

B  ClusterService  node1                Y          N               ONLINE
B  ClusterService  node2                Y          N               OFFLINE
B  NFSExport       node1                Y          N               ONLINE
B  NFSExport       node2                Y          N               OFFLINE
B  Database        node1                Y          N               ONLINE
B  Database        node2                Y          N               OFFLINE
B  Application     node1                Y          N               OFFLINE
B  Application     node2                Y          N               ONLINE
[root@node1 ~]#
```

A Service Group can run on any cluster node, and the status of every service group is reported for every cluster node, so the actual number of services groups is (servicegroups / nodes).

I've tried with and without the double braces {{ }} , but no matter what, the last debug task always produces a divide by zero error.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    # START OF BLOCK
  - name: Check cluster status
    block:
      - name: How many cluster nodes?
        shell: hastatus -sum|grep "^A"|wc -l
        register: numnodes

      - name: How many running cluster nodes?
        shell: hastatus -sum|grep "^A"|grep "RUNNING"|wc -l
        register: numrunningnodes

      - name: report if not all nodes are running
        debug:
          msg: "ACTION: Not all cluster nodes are running!"
        when: numnodes.stdout != numrunningnodes.stdout

# The number of cluster Service Groups == totalsgs / numnodes
      - name: How many SGs ("B" lines)?
        shell: hastatus -sum|grep "^B"|wc -l
        register: totalsgs

      - name: How many running SGs?
        shell: hastatus -sum|grep "^B"|grep "RUNNING"|wc -l
        register: runningsgs

      - name: Is everything running somewhere?
        debug:
          msg: "ACTION: Not all SGs are running!"
        when: {{ runningsgs.stdout|int }} != {{ totalsgs.stdout|int / numnodes.stdout|int }}
```

Comment: Take a look at *numnodes*. You'll find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. [facepalm] A "Command not found" error would be nice for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's the second worst Ansible you can write. If you throw in `include_role` with `when` and `loop` on top of that, you will have the worst worst.

Ansible is not designed to be a good algorithmic language. It's really good at doing side-effects and juggling inventories, but it's terrible at doing math. You *can* do it, but it will be unreadable, non-debuggable, non-testable, and you will have your variables littered with global variables (which will for sure bite you later when you do not expect it).

How to do it right? The best best way is to write own module. Which is easier than you think (if you know Python).

The second best (which may be even better for small projects than custom module) is to use `script` or `command` module.

Just shovel data as input to the stdin script, and get well processed data back from stdout. The main trick is to produce stdout output in json format and parse it with `|from_json` filter.

This is example of use of command to parse data:

```
 - name: Get data from somewhere
   shell: hastatus -sum
   changed_when: false
   register: hastatus_cmd

 - name: Process data
   delegate_to: localhost
   command:
     cmd: process_hastatus_output.py
     stdin: '{{ hastatus_cmd.stdout }}'
   changed_when: false
   register: hastatus_data

 - name: Use it
   command: ...?...
   when: hastatus.running != hastatus.nodes
   vars:
     hastatus: '{{ hastatus_data.stdout|from_json }}'
```

For `process_hastatus_output.py` you can write tests, you can run them without ansible to check of edge cases, and you'll have the beautiful, cosy language to transform your data.

Or, you can do it in mix of Jinja and Ansible, causing irreparable harm to yourself, and everyone reading your code later.